# Matlab Plot is running really slow

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot

I recently got a gaming computer with an Intel i7 core, a GEFORCE GTX Nvidia 4GB graphics card, and 16GB RAM. I need to plot a graph with lots of points (around 50,000) and some specific points are marked with different colors.

I can't even zoom in or move the graph around since it's running extremely slow. Is there any way to speed it up? It shouldn't be a problem for my computer, specially this simple graph...

This is the code:

```
plot(1:length(real_slope),real_slope,'y-*',1:length(real_slope),Y,'r-*')
hold on;
candle(trade_high2(26:end),trade_low2(26:end),trade_close2(26:end),trade_open2(26:end));

for i=2:length(OUT2)

    if Y(i) > Y(i-1) + threshold
        if OUT2(i) < OUT2(i-1)
            error_sum = error_sum + 1;

        end
        hold on;
        plot(i,Y(i),'x','LineWidth',5);
    end

    if Y(i) < Y(i-1) - threshold
        if OUT2(i) > OUT2(i-1)
            error_sum = error_sum + 1;
        end
        hold on;
        plot(i,Y(i),'x','LineWidth',5);
    end    


end
```

Is there any way to speed up the process? I basically just want to graph a candlestick chart, and at the same time mark with a point (or an "x") some specific points in time. I am basically plotting these specific points as "plot(i,Y(i),'x','LineWidth',5);" within a for loop. Is there a more efficient way to mark those points?

Comment: yes, this is because instead of creating 1 or 2 graphic object (`plot`) containing 25-50000 points ... you create 50,000 individual graphic objects. That'll be slow on any machine. I understand you want to create a style of candle chart, but 50,000 candle on a screen which only has 4000 pixels wide at the max, is that really necessary ? If you just want a standard plot, then pack your points in groups in a few `plot` objects and you'll be ok.

Comment: Well creating different plots is an option... But Is there any way to mark the specific points I want in the graph instead of creating around 50000 different plot objects? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is a way (probably many actually), but your question is not clear enough yet to be sure to answer. Edit your question to give detail, show the current output and show how you would really want the output (make a simple sketch if necessary, or explain it in detail). If you add information, please do so in the original post and not in comments.

Comment: Just added a little more details. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could really benefit from the use of the [`diff`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function.

Using that, and if I understand your code correctly, this should do the same quicker and easier for the graphic engine. Replace your `FOR` loop with the following:

```
Yd = [0 diff(Y)] ;                  %// return a vector of the increment between each point
idxPos = find( Yd >  threshold ) ;  %// get all indices of increment >  threshold
idxNeg = find( Yd < -threshold ) ;  %// get all indices of increment < -threshold

%// now just plot 2 sets of points
hold on
plot( idxPos , Y(idxPos) ,'x','MarkerWidth',5,'LineStyle','none' , 'DisplayName','Positive range');
plot( idxNeg , Y(idxNeg) ,'x','MarkerWidth',5,'LineStyle','none' , 'DisplayName','Negative range');
hold off

%// Use the same "diff" trick for "OUT2"
diffOUT = [0 diff(OUT2)] ;
error_sum = sum( diffOUT(idxPos)<0 ) + sum( diffOUT(idxNeg)>0 ) ;
```

Note that I didn't make a line visible between the points, so you could even plot that in **one** single graphic plot if that's all you need. I kept them separate as two different sets in case you want to display them in a different manner.